# Is point Inside Multi Polygon Or Multi Line String

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, gis

I know how to check a [point in a polygon. But my main problem is a GEOJSON consist of multi data types such a Polygon, Multi Polygon and Multi Line String. How can I achieve the solution? Should I use library or is there specific algorithm for this kind of problems? My priority is to achieve the solution with native JavaScript.
here is simplified GEOJSON.

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
              
                [
                    49.111221438,
                    30.10109108299997
                ],
                [
                    49.113533168000096,
                    30.103797081000025
                ],
                [
                    49.11106481600011,
                    30.106136648000103
                ],
                [
                    49.11442937499999,
                    30.107470637000134
                ],
                [
                    49.1161612860001,
                    30.106002348000118
                ],
                [
                    49.116107924000104,
                    30.10155146799997
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                [
                    48.7795410730001,
                    30.143445568000075
                ],
                [
                    48.7763593770001,
                    30.145010960999997
                ],
                [
                    48.7753754230001,
                    30.14971452600001
                ],
                [
                    48.7795410730001,
                    30.143445568000075
                ]
            ]
        ],
]
```

]
}

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
    "FNODE_": 33,
    "TNODE_": 61,
    "LPOLY_": 1,
    "RPOLY_": 1,
    "LENGTH": 70009.96,
    "CON_ALL_": 31,
    "CON_ALL_ID": 6567,
    "DXF_ELEVAT": 900
},
"geometry": {
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                52.50931406450401,
                34.41497301767497
            ],
            [
                52.50794987983731,
                34.41395625923523
            ],
            [
                52.50696974128559,
                34.41136455807418
            ],
            [
                52.503155059152384,
                34.411328093408954
            ],
            [
                52.50072840199781,
                34.41130153688085
            ],
            [
                52.49934365428397,
                34.41128470636023
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                52.51899510810492,
                34.41309054333186
            ],
            [
                52.5180432345018,
                34.41234125510482
            ],
            [
                52.51612423451168,
                34.413660624347564
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanIntersects